# How to preserve language status using PHP sessions and cookies

Tags: php, session, cookies

I have this in my index.php:

`<?php include_once 'file.php' ?>`
then I have `<html> some content </html>`

and I have this in file.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
header('Cache-control: private');

if(isSet($_GET['lang']))
{
$lang = $_GET['lang'];

$_SESSION['lang'] = $lang;

setcookie("lang", $lang, time() + (3600 * 24 * 30));
}
else if(isSet($_SESSION['lang']))
{
$lang = $_SESSION['lang'];
}
else if(isSet($_COOKIE['lang']))
{
$lang = $_COOKIE['lang'];
}
else
{
$lang = 'en';
}

switch ($lang) {
  case 'en':
  $lang_file = 'lang.en.php';
  break;

  case 'de':
  $lang_file = 'lang.de.php';
  break;

  case 'es':
  $lang_file = 'lang.es.php';
  break;

  default:
  $lang_file = 'lang.en.php';

}

include_once 'languages/'.$lang_file;
?>
```

I have those 3 files, I mean lang.en.php an so on...

and it doesn't work, my page is empty, no text, why? What's wrong?

lang.en.php contains

```
<?php


$h1 ="HOME";
$h2 ="ABOUT US";
$h3 ="CONTACT";
$h4 ="FAQ";

$txt1 = "Here goes txt,Here goes txt,Here goes txt,Here goes txt,
         Here goes txt,Here goes txt,Here goes txt,Here goes txt,
         Here goes txt, Here goes txt,Here goes txt,Here goes txt.";
?>
```

I don't know what's wrong with this... What should I change? 
Can someone help me. Thanks.

Comment: What do these lang.en.php files contain ? Also, what does `$lang` and `$lang_file` contain if you print them ?

Comment: **never** preserve language status using sessions or cookies. But use address string elements only. subdomain (e.g. en.wikipedia.org) is the best choice, then path or query string.

Answer (score 1):

You are not printing anything except some HTML. To see the contents of the strings in your lang.en.php's files, you'll need to output them using an `echo` language construct.

```
<?php
echo $txt1;
?>
```

would output:

> ```
> Here goes txt,Here goes txt,Here goes txt,Here goes txt,
> Here goes txt,Here goes txt,Here goes txt,Here goes txt,
> Here goes txt, Here goes txt,Here goes txt,Here goes txt.
> ```

Comment: I have that in index.php, why do I need this in file.php?

Comment: If you have that in index.php, you don't need it in file.php. The code you've posted works, so its indicating the issue is likely with index.php. Can you please post your index.php file?

Answer (score 0):

Problems like these effectively never occur when you use proper code structuring: indent control structures, haven controllers (logic) and views (presentation). You are mixing up a lot stuff there in one file which makes it obviously difficult for you and others to read and understand the code. Please try to code with readability/maintainability in mind, even if you are using php.

Answer (score 0):

I tested you code (it's from Bitrepository tutprial right :)

Ok, the `file.php` should be in your `function.php` if ever you have one.

I assume you had `index.php` and it echoed those variables from your language files right like:

```
echo $h1;

echo $h2;

echo $h3;

echo $txt1;
```

To change language, see your `file.php`, it's specified in the cases. If you want english:

```
index.php?lang=en

index.php?lang=de

index.php?lang=es
```

And so on.

Easy right `\(^_^)/`

Check bitrepository for much detailed tutorial. I also would like to suggest to use `define()` for your language files.

ex.

```
define('TITLE', 'This is the title')
```

To echo:

```
echo TITLE;
```

Answer (score 0):

You must define array in lang.en.php, lang.ru.php...

lang.en.php

```
$lang = array();
$lang["PAGE_TITLE"] = "Some title";
$lang["MENU_HOME"] = "Home";
$lang["HOME_CONTENT"] = "Some content";
```

lang.ru.php

```
$lang = array();
$lang["PAGE_TITLE"] = "Russian title";
$lang["MENU_HOME"] = "Russian home";
$lang["HOME_CONTENT"] = "Russian content"; ...
```

Then, output it in your pages.

```
<?php echo $lang["PAGE_HOME"]; ?>
<?php echo $lang["MENU_HOME"]; ?>
<?php echo $lang["HOME_CONTENT"]; ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

`session_start()` needs to be at the top of your document.

The session must start before something is sent to the browser.